# Value error in fitting linear regression model

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I started to make a predictive model for USD to INR conversion.
I splitted the data, converted dates into ordinal format and fitted it into LinearRegression model.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
data = pd.read_csv("FED-RXI_N_M_IN.csv")
rates = {}
rates = {'date':[x for x in data.Date],
         'rate':[y for y in data.Value]}
df = pd.DataFrame(rates, columns = ["date", "rate"])
dates = df['date']
rates = df['rate']
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)
dates = dates.map(dt.datetime.toordinal)

#train data
dates_test = dates[0:110]
rates_test = rates[0:110]

#test data
dates_train = dates[110:543]
rates_train = rates[110:543]

plt.plot_date(dates_test, rates_test, fmt="g-")
plt.title('US-INR Currency Predictor')
plt.ylabel("INR rate against $1")
plt.xlabel("Date")

#training
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(dates_train,rates_train)
rates_pred = regr.predict(dates_test)
plt.scatter(dates_test, rates_test,  color='black')
plt.title('Test Data')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Rate')
plt.plot(dates_test, rates_pred, color = 'red', linewidth= 3)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.show()
print( str((regr.predict(736753))) )
```

I am getting this error at `regr.fit(dates_train,rates_train)`

[image]

Please help me how to resolve it. I am beginner in this field.

Comment: Any reason why you're reading the csv with pandas and then building a dictionary from that, and then making a new dataframe with the dictionary?

Comment: Just for extracting useful data from given data

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **sklearn** requires the data shape of `(row number, column number)`. For this, you can use `reshape` method.

Also, you need to pass a `numpy` array as input to `fit` method.

```
rates = df['rate'].values.reshape(len(df.index), 1)   

#train data
dates_test = dates[0:110, :]
rates_test = rates[0:110, :]

#test data
dates_train = dates[110:543, :]
rates_train = rates[110:543, :]
```

Comment: Thanks, but reshaping with (433,1) and (110,1) without converting to numpy array, solved the problem

Comment: @AshutoshAgrahari, i mentioned in my answer that you need to reshape the data using `reshape` method.